# How to do feature extraction to build models for sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, twitter, data-science, sentiment-analysis, feature-extraction

I'm trying to do feature extraction and build a model for a twitter sentiment analysis project. However, I'm getting the following error, and I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Error:

```
ValueError: np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

My code:

```
import re
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


# nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

# sklearn

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
df = pd.read_csv("updated_tweet_info.csv")


train,test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)

train_clean_tweet=[]
for tweet in train['tweet']:
    train_clean_tweet.append(tweet)
test_clean_tweet=[]
for tweet in test['tweet']:
    test_clean_tweet.append(tweet)

v = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word")
train_features= v.fit_transform(train_clean_tweet)
test_features=v.transform(test_clean_tweet)

lr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200)
fit = lr.fit(train)
pred = lr.predict(test)
accuracy = r2_score(train,test)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing NaN's with white spaces - this should remove the error:

```
data = df.fillna(' ')
```